# Will MySQL use Multiple-column index if I use columns in different order?

Tags: mysql

Reading the MySQL [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/multiple-column-indexes.html) we see this example table with multiple-column index `name`:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    id         INT NOT NULL,
    last_name  CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    first_name CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    INDEX name (last_name,first_name)
);
```

It is explained with examples in which cases the index will or will not be utilized. For example, it will be used for such query:

```
SELECT * FROM test
  WHERE last_name='Widenius' AND first_name='Michael';
```

My question is, would it work for this query (which is effectively the same):

```
SELECT * FROM test
  WHERE first_name='Michael' AND last_name='Widenius';
```

I couldn't find any word about that in the documentation - does MySQL try to swap columns to find appropriate index or is it all up to the query?

Comment: Why don't you simply run a test to find out?

Comment: @arkascha maybe it might work on some storage engines and not work on others. Maybe there are other hidden dependances on server/database/table configuration. I can't test all the possible configurations...

Comment: I'm pretty sure the order of tests makes no difference.

Comment: The order of columns in an index makes a difference if you only test a subset of the columns, because the index will work with a prefix of the columns. But order in the query is irrelevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be the same because (from mysql doc) the query optiminzer work looking at

> Each table index is queried, and the best index is used unless the
>   optimizer believes that it is more efficient to use a table scan. At
>   one time, a scan was used based on whether the best index spanned more
>   than 30% of the table, but a fixed percentage no longer determines the
>   choice between using an index or a scan. The optimizer now is more
>   complex and bases its estimate on additional factors such as table
>   size, number of rows, and I/O block size.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/where-optimizations.html

> In some cases, MySQL can read rows from the index without even
>   consulting the data file.

and this should be you case

> Without ICP, the storage engine traverses the index to locate rows in
>   the base table and returns them to the MySQL server which evaluates
>   the WHERE condition for the rows. With ICP enabled, and if parts of
>   the WHERE condition can be evaluated by using only fields from the
>   index, the MySQL server pushes this part of the WHERE condition down
>   to the storage engine. The storage engine then evaluates the pushed
>   index condition by using the index entry and only if this is satisfied
>   is the row read from the table. ICP can reduce the number of times the
>   storage engine must access the base table and the number of times the
>   MySQL server must access the storage engine.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/index-condition-pushdown-optimization.html

Answer (score 2):

For the two queries you stated, it will work the same.

However, for queries which have only one of the columns, the order of the index matters.

For example, this will use the index:

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE last_name='Widenius';
```

But this wont:

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE first_name='Michael';
```